# Rewrite Sql at runtime

Tags: c#

I have a SQL statement with parameters eg.

```
SELECT * 
FROM persons 
WHERE id = @id 
  AND firstName = @firstname
   OR surname = @surname
```

I would like to use c# to rewrite the statement based on the parameters supplied at run-time.

Example if at runtime, `@firstname` is not provided, then my SQL should be re-written to

```
SELECT * 
FROM persons 
WHERE id = @id OR surname = @surname
```

This is what I have so far.

```
public class SqlRewriter
{
    public string RewriteSql(List<string> passedRuntimeParameter )
    {
        var sql = @"SELECT * FROM persons 
                 WHERE id=@id AND firstName=@firstname
                 or surname=@surname";
        /**
         * todo parse the sql and compare with passedRuntimeParameter.
         * todo reconstruct the sql based on parsed parameters
         */

        return sql;
    }
}
```

Comment: So use ADO Sql parameters - http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Comment: as a matter of style putting parens in to be explicit makes it easier to know intent.   ex: WHERE id=@id AND (firstName=@firstname or surname=@surname)

Answer (score 3):

```
IF @firstname = Null {
    SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id=@id or surname=@surname
} else {
    SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id=@id AND firstName=@firstname or surname=@surname
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation this works perfectly looking at the way i framed the question, but the problem is that, I am pulling the sql from an RDLC definition, so i am not ware of the names of the parameters until runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could write instead:

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE
    (id=@id OR @id is null) AND
    (
        (firstName=@firstname OR @firstname is null) OR
        (surname=@surname OR @surname is null)
    )
```

And send nulls when you don't have the specified value

Or well if you really want to omit the parameter, you can do it like mikey or Patrick answered.

But keep in mind that if you really want to query based on the parameters you have, (**id and surname**, or just **firstname**, or **firstname + surname**), you would end up with a lot of ifs in case you're willing to customize your query string.

Answer (score 0):

```
if FirstName==NULL
{
 sqlQuery="ConstructYourQueryfor This condition";
}
else
{
 sqlQuery="Another Construction for else Query";
}
```

USE SQLCommand Parameters

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("your connectionstring goes here"))
{
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery,                                                                          connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id ", yourIDvalue);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname ", FirstName);    
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", surname);    
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation this works perfectly looking at the way i framed the question, but the problem is that, I am pulling the sql from an RDLC definition, so i am not ware of the names of the parameters until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You're using parameterized queries which is good.  You can use an if block to do what you want or even an inline if.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id=@id" + ((firstname!=null&&firstname!=string.Empty) ? " AND firstname=@firstname OR surname=@surname" : " AND surname=@surname");
// setup command with query
// setup parameters (remember to check if you need to provide a firstname parameter or not)
```

good luck

Comment: This might be more clear and less repeated code: string query = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id=@id AND ( surname=@surname " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname) ? string.Empty : "OR surname=@surname"") + ")";

Comment: Thanks for this explanation this works perfectly looking at the way i framed the question, but the problem is that, I am pulling the sql from an RDLC definition, so i am not ware of the names of the parameters until runtime and each parameter must be treated as independent.

Comment: @jsobo  I like it! There is a IsNullOrEmpty method -- I learned something new today.  Thank you!

Comment: @GyidiAsare - How do you know what parameter is what, if you're just getting a List of strings as input to your method?  i.e. how do you know which item in the list is intended for which parameter?  If you know that then you should be able to rewrite the SQL as you wish fairly simply

Comment: thats Great. the thing is that the RDLC provides the parameters its needs. Based on the parameters, I build say an interface to get the parameter values at runtime. But i am not certain of the values will be provided. and the AND , OR used in the query

Comment: @GyidiAsare - Is the query always going to be the same at first?

Comment: @ Mikey, the queries will always vary